# react-native : image import err : None of these files exist

Tags: react-native

I am trying to import an img.JPG photo in my React Native project using import image from './media/img.JPG';.

But I get an error saying the file doesn't exist

For reference, my files look like this:

[image]

[image]

It came out well on the screen when the external path was inserted.

Comment: could you add the code you tried and the error exactly that you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

In your question, you say the image name is img.PNG, but in the code it says img.JPG. Could that be the issue?

Comment: If you don't mind, can you accept my response as an answer? Thanks!